# Sub view for $state not rendering in named ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

https://plnkr.co/edit/VV13ty8XaQ20tdqibmFy?p=preview

#### Expected

After <kbd>login</kbd> the `dashboard` state renders dashboard.html, and all components and ui-views should render: **tickers**, **tags**, **social**(named ui-view) and **feed**.

#### Results

After <kbd>login</kbd> the `dashboard` state renders dashboard.html however only the components **tickers**,**tags** and **feed** show up, but not the **social** (named-ui-view)

I feel that my problem lies somewhere around where I transition from the `login` state to the `dashboard` state. Once you hit the dashboard state, it serves up the default template which is the component element tag: `<dash-module></dash-module>`. This will then render the dash.component template: dashboard.html and controller. However I've lost access to the social view in the dashboard state object.

---

**dashboard.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>The Dashboard</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <tickers-module></tickers-module>
  <tags-module></tags-module>

  // Expecting the social-module-template.html to show below:
  <div ui-view="social"></div> 

  <feed-module></feed-module>
</div>
```

**The routerApp module with the dashboard component** full code in [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/VV13ty8XaQ20tdqibmFy?p=preview)

```
// RouterApp module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router', 'tickers', 'tags', 'feed']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    const login = {
      name: 'login',
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: 'l',
      controller: function($state) {
        this.login = function() {
          $state.go('dashboard', {});
        }
      }
    }

    const dashboard = {
      name: 'dashboard',
      url: '/dashboard',
      params: {
        ticker: {},
        tags: {}
      },
      template: '<dash-module></dash-module>',
      views: {
        '' : {
          templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
        },
        'social' : {
          templateUrl: 'social-module-template.html', 
          controller: function($state) {
            console.log('Social init', $state.params);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $stateProvider
      .state(login)
      .state(dashboard);
})
tags.component('dashModule', {
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    console.log('dashModule loaded!');
  }
})
```

---

This is the part that should render the social html content in the `<div ui-view="social"></div>`

```
views: {
  '' : {
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
  },
  'social' : {
    templateUrl: 'social-module-template.html', 
    controller: function($state) {
      console.log('Social init', $state.params);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made changes to your plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8OrdubHEI1gblgiQ6yeG?p=preview) You were missing @ here.

```
const dashboard = {
  name: 'dashboard',
  url: '/dashboard',
  params: {
    ticker: {},
    tags: {}
  },
  template: '<dash-module></dash-module>',
  views: {
    '' : {
      templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
    },
    'social@dashboard' : {
      templateUrl: 'social-module-template.html', 
      controller: function($state) {
        console.log('Social init', $state.params);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> In order for these components to appear under the home state, we must define them using absolute naming. Specifically, we must use the @ syntax to tell AngularJS that these components of our application should be mapped to a specific state. This follows the viewName@stateName syntax and tells our application to utilize named views from an absolute, or specific state. You can read more about relative vs. absolute names [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names).

See [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/write-modular-code-angular-ui-router-named-views/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks man! Btw another question about ui-router state navigation :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862998/how-to-send-object-from-1-state-into-another-state-with-ui-router

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is named view has to render in same state i.e Dashboard.

Change the following and it should work.

```
social@dashboard
```

Check this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/59hThXx14YFKISLHfFP8?p=preview)

[Named Views UI router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)