# How to prevent specific $state from refreshing when another $state updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, state-machine

https://plnkr.co/edit/bOZW1a9u62W1QA6cYjYj?p=preview

#### Expected

After <kbd>Login</kbd> all $states initialize, then after clicking a Ticker button, the only $states that should re-init are **ticker**, **tags** and **social**, but not **feed**.

#### Results

After <kbd>Login</kbd> all $states initialize, then after clicking a Ticker button all $states re-initialized. The **feed** should not.

[image]

How should the dashboard and feed module be architected to prevent this? At the moment I have the `<feed-module></feed-module>` inside the `dashboard.html`. Should it and the dashboard be further separated out in another in-between state/component? A container.component perhaps?

Full code

```
// Feed module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var feed = angular.module('feed', ['ui.router'])

feed.config(function($stateProvider) {
  
  const feed = {
    name: 'feed',
    url: '/feed',
    templateUrl: '<em>Feed items go here.</em>'
  }
  
  $stateProvider.state(feed);
  
})

feed.component('feedModule', {
  templateUrl: 'feed-module-template.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    console.log('Feed init (only once)', $state.params);
  }
})

// RouterApp module
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router', 'feed']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    const login = {
      name: 'login',
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: 'l',
      controller: function($state) {
        this.login = function() {
          $state.go('dashboard', {});
        }
      }
    }

    const dashboard = {
      name: 'dashboard',
      url: '/dashboard',
      params: {
        ticker: {},
        tags: {}
      },
      views: {
        '' : {
          templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
        },
        'tickers@dashboard': {
          templateUrl: 'tickers-module-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            console.log('Tickers init', $state.params);
        
            $scope.tickers = [
              { id: 1, ticker: 'AAPL' },
              { id: 2, ticker: 'GOOG' },
              { id: 3, ticker: 'TWTR' }
            ];
            
            $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
              console.log(' ')
              console.log('Ticker clicked!')
              $state.go('dashboard', { ticker: ticker });
            }
          }
        },
        'tags@dashboard' : {
          templateUrl: 'tags-module-template.html',
          controller: function($scope, $state) {
            const tags_model = [
              {
                ticker: 'AAPL',
                tags : [{ id: 1, term: 'iPhone 7' }, { id: 2, term: 'iPhone 8' }, { id: 3, term: 'Tim Cook' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'GOOG',
                tags : [{ id: 4, term: 'Pixel' }, { id: 5, term: 'Pixel XL' }, { id: 6, term: 'Chrome Book' }]
              },
              {
                ticker: 'TWTR',
                tags : [{ id: 7, term: 'tweet' }, { id: 8, term: 'retweet' }, { id: 9, term: 'moments' }]
              }
            ];
            
            function matchTags(ticker, model) {
              return model.filter(function(obj){
                if (obj.ticker === ticker) { return obj; }
              });
            }
            
            $scope.tags_model = matchTags($state.params.ticker.ticker, tags_model)[0];
            
            $scope.clickTag = function(tag) {
              $state.go('tags', { tag: tag });
            }
            
            console.log('Tags init', $state.params);
            // console.log(' Tags model', tags_model);
          }
        },
        'social@dashboard' : {
          templateUrl: 'social-module-template.html', 
          controller: function($state) {
            console.log('Social init', $state.params);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $stateProvider
      .state(login)
      .state(dashboard);
});
```

Thoughts, would an architecture like this work? Basically `login` would navigate to a `container` state which will contain 2 components (`dashboard` and `feed`) each with their own internal states?

[image]

Comment: I think this is not possible. Notify all, notify none or reload current state with/without notifiy would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve this issue depending on which state you're coming from. Based on the fact that you only want the feed to be loaded 'once' when dashboard is loaded, I'm checking the name of the previous state, and if it is not dashboard, only then I'll proceed with executing the rest of the controller code. Here is the plunker. Note that this is not very scalable approach if more states are added and if someone else has a better approach, I'd really like to see that.

I changed the controller code as follows:

```
feed.component('feedModule', {
  templateUrl: 'feed-module-template.html',
  controller: function($scope, $state) {
    var previousState = $state.params.previousState.name;
    if(previousState !== 'dashboard') {
      console.log('Feed init (only once)', $state.params); //do whatever u want here
    }
  }
});
```

I'm passing around previous state as params to other states like this:

```
controller: function($state) {
  this.login = function() {
    $state.go('dashboard', {previousState : { name : $state.current.name }})
  }
}
```

Look at the full plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/O3H7SOeDZoB9WniSvRVC?p=preview) to see if this helps your case!

Comment: Thank you, yes that did work! I also got to the same conclusion that I needed another $state after the login. However now I'm facing a new issue, would you mind a look see here? Worth `200` points :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865321/how-to-pass-state-variable-into-2-other-sibling-states

Comment: sure I'll take a look at it today.